Webpage not getting connected to mainnet fork
I've been trying to implement a clone of uniswap using the uniswap-v3 sdk. Now to get a quote for the exchange, I tried to get the signer object using the following code
import { ethers } from "ethers";
import CurrentConfig from "../../CurrentConfig";

export async function getProvider() {
  console.log(ethers);
  let x = new ethers.JsonRpcProvider(CurrentConfig.rpc.mainnet);
  console.log(x);
  return x;
}

But in the console, it is printed as the following
destroyed:false
disableCcipRead:false
paused:false
plugins:Array(0)
pollingInterval:4000
provider: JsonRpcProvider
ready:false
_network:[Exception: Error: network is not available yet (code=NETWORK_ERROR, version=6.13.2) at makeError (http://localhost:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/ethers.js?v=265ae4cc:325:15) at assert (http://localhost:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/ethers.js?v=265ae4cc:338:11) at get _network (http://localhost:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/ethers.js?v=265ae4cc:18725:5) at JsonRpcProvider.invokeGetter (<anonymous>:3:28)]
[[Prototype]]
: 
JsonRpcApiPollingProvider

